# docker swarm init made docker go corrupted

Tags: docker, linux

I started learning docker recently and I set up a virtual machine (VirtualBox) with Lubuntu image:

- Linux verion: `Linux 4.18.0-10-generic i686`
- Docker version: `18.06.1-ce`, API-version: `1.38`, Go version: `go1.10.4`, Git commit: `e68fc7a`

So unless I have started acquaintance with swarm everything was going smoothly. However after I executed `docker swarm init` daemon seemed going down and whatever command I'm now trying to execute, it responds with: `Cannot connect to Docker daemon at..`

When I'm trying to run `sudo dockerd` it shows the output where there're some warnings like `failed to load plugin io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.btrfa` and one error saying `error creating cluster object... error="name conflicts with an existing object" module=node node.id=...`. Eventually the output ends with `floating point exception` with some address in memory.

Restarting does not help. The only things that makes docker run is reverting to the snapshot that I luckily made before calling `swarm init`.

So I would appreciate your help or advice how I do fix everything out.

Answer (score 5):

This response is for 
Kernel: Linux 4.4.132-1075-rockchip-ayufan-ga83beded8524
Architecture: aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux

I had the same issue when issuing commands to a cluster in swarm mode.

Running `docker info` would result in `Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?`

Running `sudo systemctl start docker` would result in a failed service state and output reading

```
Job for docker.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status docker.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Running `systemctl status docker.service` would result in

```
docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2019-05-16 06:03:46 UTC; 1min 12s ago
     Docs: https://docs.docker.com
  Process: 3874 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock (cod
 Main PID: 3874 (code=exited, status=2)
```

Running `journalctl -xe` wouldn't result in any information related to docker

Running `sudo dockerd -D` would result in lots of output with a certain line reading
`error="name conflicts with an existing object" module=node node.id=105rworelt1fvw9ttjhnf61aw`

Looking in `/var/lib/docker` there is a folder called `swarm` and doing a grep on all files and folders in the swarm directory for the 
string `105rworelt1fvw9ttjhnf61aw` came up with two files with the string `105rworelt1fvw9ttjhnf61aw` in them.
sudo grep -r "105rworelt1fvw9ttjhnf61aw" /var/lib/docker/swarm/

Those two files were `/var/lib/docker/swarm/.tmp-state.json504201306` and `/var/lib/docker/swarm/state.json`

At this point I wasn't feeling very surgical so I removed all files and folders under the `/var/lib/docker/swarm` and then tried `sudo systemctl start docker` again

```
A bit surgical: sudo rm -ri /var/lib/docker/swarm/
```

Note: Don't delete the `swarm` directory. If you do just create it again.

After this a `docker info` would work and I was able to `docker swarm init` again and deploy a stack without issues